# Spring Boot Authentication Auditing Support With Starter Actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, event-listener, spring-boot-actuator

```
@Component
public class LoginAttemptsLogger {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorisationLogService authorisationLogService;

    @EventListener
    public void auditEventHappened(AuditApplicationEvent auditApplicationEvent) {

        AuditEvent auditEvent = auditApplicationEvent.getAuditEvent();

        String principal = auditEvent.getPrincipal();
        if (!principal.equals("anonymousUser")) {
            if (auditEvent.getType().equals("AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS")) {
                authorisationLogService.logSuccessfulLogin(principal);
            } else {
                authorisationLogService.logUnSuccessfulLogin(principal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Problem Occured in @EventListener. It was Working on Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE.
- When I update My project to Spring Boot 2.6.1 ,    Request doesn't
  automatically go into this method anymore, as it was    before.
- ***How Can I fix it ?***
- ***[SOURCE CODE on BAELDUNG](https://baeldung-cn.com/spring-boot-authentication-audit)***